# Where are .deb package control files located?

Tags: package-management, packaging

My understanding is that debian based packages have "control files" which specify metadata on how the packages is to be installed, e.g. what dependencies it has etc.

How can I view these files for installed packages?

Comment: Some of the metadata is located in `/var/lib/dpkg/info`; however, those are just the files installed and the pre/post (un)installation scripts.

Comment: thanks, in my machine `/var/lib/dpkg/info` is empty but good to know for the future

Comment: That's odd. Does `dpkg -L base-files` list anything?

Comment: `dpkg -L base-files ` list about 50 or so directories , including `/var/lib/dpkg` but doesnt include `/var/lib/dpkg/info`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the .deb file in file roller or whatever archiver you have on your system. Then go to the `debian` folder.  In there, you will find the file `control` which contains the metadata.

Comment: thanks for the response, the packages I'm looking at are already installed -  I dont have a .deb file available - do you know where I would check in that case?

Comment: search for deb files inside the /var/cache/apt/archives there you will find installed debs if you havent removed manually

Comment: the install paths are in the  /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.list files and you can see the dependency's with apt-cache depends <package name>   and you can just open synaptic and find the package you are interested in , click it,and then from the menu package>property’s to see all this as well .

Answer (score 11):

For dependency information, you can see `/var/lib/dpkg/status`, which basically lists the contents of `debian/control` (with some additional information about the package itself) for each installed package.

Additionally, you can look into `/var/lib/dpkg/info` to see the files installed, pre/post (un)installation scripts (if any), and configuration files (if any) for each installed package.

Comment: this looks right on - i.e. looks like its showing dependency info as well as current status. Is this the data that the command `dpkg -s <package name>` will look up against to find its info?

Comment: Using `strace`, at least `/var/lib/dpkg/status` is used by that command. I can't confirm that the `/var/lib/dpkg/info` is used, but I would think it is. EDIT: The `/var/lib/dpkg/info` folder is not used by that command, but is probably used by `dpkg -S <file name>` (when finding out what package a file comes from).

Comment: upvote, very useful answer as this information is always available, I've gone with Charles Wrights answer as it seems in order to get the full picture you need to get your hands on the actual `.deb` package

Answer (score 5):

The *deb file are not kept for installed packages. To view the control file for a given package:

```
apt download <package name>
dpkg-deb -I <package name*deb> control
```

To get a list of installed packages:

```
apt list --installed
```